# Why I add an "&" ,it outputs different?

Tags: c++

I've asked a similar question before ([Why the code doesn't work on CodeBlocks,but on VS works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56075317/)).
Now a new error confused me.

`cout << ++a1 << endl;` will call the function `operator double()`.

If in the code `Fraction& operator++()` I remove the `&` to make it `Fraction operator++()`, it will call the `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,  Fraction&& obj)`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Fraction
{
private:
    int fenzi, fenmu;
public:
    Fraction(int a, int b) :fenzi(a), fenmu(b) {}
    operator double()
    {
        return 1.0* fenzi / fenmu;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,  Fraction&& obj)
    {
        os << obj.fenzi << "/" << obj.fenmu;
        return os;
    }
    Fraction& operator++()
    {
        fenzi++;
        fenmu++;
        return *this;
    }
    Fraction operator++(int)
    {
        Fraction tmp(fenzi, fenmu);
        fenzi++;
        fenmu++;
        return tmp;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Fraction a1(9, 11), a2(1, 2);
    cout << double(a2) << endl;
    cout << ++a1 << endl;
    cout << a1++ << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I wonder why is the output different?

`Fraction operator++()` and `Fraction& operator++()`, the former returns a copied one, and the latter returns the original one. But their types are both `Fraction`. I think it should have both called `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,  Fraction&& obj)`.

Fraction operator++() output(I expected):

```
0.5
10/12
10/12
```

Fraction& operator++() output:

```
0.5
0.833333
10/12
```

Comment: Please include actual and expected output

Comment: Not sure why you are confused.  You can't pass a lvalue reference to a rvalue reference.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943276/what-does-do-in-a-c-declaration) link may can ansver your question.

Comment: If you want `++a1` argument to bind to the `Fraction&&` parameter, do it this way: `cout << std::move(++a1) << endl;`  That casts the lvalue to be used as an rvalue, which can be bound to an rvalue reference.

Comment: so in conclusion Fraction& return a l-value，Fraction return a r-value，right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
operator double()
{
    return 1.0* fenzi / fenmu;
}
```

Is the implicit conversion operator. Adding the `explicit` keyword to the `operator double()` will help with this because the compiler won't implicitly convert a `Fraction` into a `double` without you explicitly casting it into a `double`. The addition would look like:

```
explicit operator double()
{
    return 1.0* fenzi / fenmu;
}
```

The correct output stream operator is defined as 
`friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Fraction& obj)`. 
You defined it as 
`friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Fraction&& obj)` 
`Fraction&&` is a rvalue reference instead of a lvalue reference (`Fraction&`). The compiler used the implicit conversion operator because the `operator++` (in either definition) returns a lvalue (reference) instead of a rvalue reference which was defined as the parameter of the output stream operator.

Comment: The bit shift operator might technically be the same as the streams use for output, but their use dictates that they be declared differently. Notably, the first argument can't really be `const` and the return type must be a reference type.

Comment: how can i  add the explicit keyword to the operator double() ?and in conclusion Fraction& return a l-value，Fraction return a r-value，right?